# На локальном сервере не видит мой JS файл

Tags: html, node.js, express

У меня есть локальный сервер. Я его создал на `Express.JS`. У меня есть `HTML` файл, который работает, к нему можно подключиться и видеть что в нём. Но я когда подключил `index.js` файл, то мне пишет что такой файл не существует. Я в адресной строке ввёл путь этого `index.js`, но пишет:

> Cannot GET /Project/Scripts/index.js

Помогите пожалуйста.

[image: расположение]

Вот моё подключение к `JS` файлу в `HTML`:

1. `<script src="./Scripts/index.js"></script>`
2. `<script src="Scripts/index.js"></script>`
3. `<script src="Project/Scripts/index.js"></script>`

Вот что в консоли:

> GET http://localhost:8080/Project/Scripts/index.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)

Comment: А точка входа в приложение какая? Просто может быть у вас как-то переопределены пути и не надо вообще писать такой путь, а хватит `/index.js` или `index.js`

Comment: Ну, я так понимаю, что это: `localhost:8080/Project/`

Comment: @mepihindeveloper я много вариантов перепробовал.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Добавьте в `main.js`:

```js
app.use(express.static(path.join(__diraname, 'Project')));
```

Тогда ...

```
<script src="Scripts/index.js"></script>
```

... Должно сработать.

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо `Oliver Patterson`, но его ответ решает мою проблему **ЧАСТИЧНО**. Я узнал о `Express.static`, и применил его:
 `app.use(express.static('./Project/'));`.

А в **HTML**  я написал `script src`: 
`<script src="/Scripts/index.js"></script>`

Comment: Почему частично? Путь не правильный все же был?(

Comment: Да, я проверил ваше решение. Мне написало ошибку (

Comment: Какую?) Интересно.

Comment: И да, наверное правильно было бы сделать тогда: `path.join(__diraname, 'Project')`, изменил в ответе.

Comment: @OliverPatterson 1. Ну, мне кажется 404.. 2. Можно и так, но и прошлое было не хуже.